# Sql real time synchronization between non-like tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to find the best way of keeping a table populated with data from several tables in another database. In real time.

Both the databases are Microsoft Sql Server 2012 Standard.

Database A contains, for example, the following 2 tables:

NAME: [A].[dbo].OrdersToProcess
COLUMNS: OrderId, Status, NumItems

NAME: [A].[dbo].OrdersProcessed
COLUMNS: OrderId, Status, NumItems, TimeProcessed

Database B contains the following table:

Name: [B].[dbo].Orders
COLUMNS: OrderId, Status, NumItems, Processed, TimeProcessed

What would the best method to update database B with data from the two tables in database A?

In the above example OrdersToProcess would fill table [B].[dbo].Orders with the OrderId, Status, NumItems, insert FALSE into Processed and leave TimeProcessed as null

OrdersProcessed would fill table [B].[dbo].Orders with OrderId, Status, NumItem,TimeProcessed and insert TRUE into Processed.

To achieve real time syncing between databases I have previously used sql replication, but I don't know if this can be done for non-identical tables???

The only other option I can think of is to run a MERGE command at an interval, however this isn't truly real time.

Does any one know of any tool/method which can do this, or anyone tried to achieve the same thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways you can solve this issue.  (in no particular order)

1. Create an incrememental ETL process that picks up changes from database A and loads them into Database B.  You can do the transformations in the ETL package or load the data into a staging table for processing.  You can run this every x minutes.
2. Create triggers on your tables in database A that use linked servers to load the data into database B. (* You could even leverage service broker to create a message to send to b with the data)
3. Create some form of messaging platform that is initiated when the tables in A have a DML operation.  This will then send a message to database B to grab the data from database A and insert it.  Note: (this could also take the form of a remote stored procedure execution on B that simply pulls the new data and loads it).

The method you choose is going depend on your environment and how the testing of each method goes.